# Spilt timestamp into separate columns in Stream Analytics for further filtering in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

Currently am i receiving data from sensors (via Event Hub) to Stream Analytics i JSON format. I want to visualize these data in Power BI and would like to filter the events to specific days, month, year etc. But for to be able to do this, I need to split the timestamp into new columns. I am receiving the timestamp in ISO 8601 format:

"timestamp": "2020-01-13T08:24:50.0749840Z"

I have not been able to split this kind of timestamp in Stream analytics. Is there anyone that has done this before?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: So sorry, forgot answer you. Yes, i helped very much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just use built-in [Date and Time Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/date-and-time-functions-azure-stream-analytics) in ASA which could identify format of your date data.

sql:

```
SELECT
     Year(input.timestamp) as year,
     Month(input.timestamp) as month,
     Day(input.timestamp) as day
FROM
      input
```

Output:

[image]